# Facebook Php API: RSVP users to public event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to use the facebook php api to rsvp users to a public event.
So far I can only get it to work for users who have already been invited.

I've tried:

```
$path = $event_id.'/attending'; 
$method = 'POST';
try
{
    $this->facebook->api($path, $method);
}
catch(FacebookApiException $e){}
```

Which does nothing.

My code as it stands is:

```
function rsvpEvent($event_id)
{
    $fb_config = array(
                    'appId'  => APP_ID, 
                    'secret' => APP_SECRET,
                    'cookie' => true,
                 );
     $this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);
     $me = $this->facebook->api('/me/');
     $user_id = $me['id'];
     $path = $event_id.'/invited/'.$user_id;
     $status = $this->facebook->api($path, 'GET');
     $status = $status['data'][0]['rsvp_status'];

     if($status === 'not_replied')
     {
          $path = $event_id.'/attending'; 
          $method = 'POST';
          try
          {
               $this->facebook->api($path, $method);
          }
          catch(FacebookApiException $e){}
      }
 }
```

Has anyone got any ideas how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $path = $event_id.'/attending?access_token='.$SOME_ACCESS_TOKEN;
```

You're not using the access token in your code, so I am uncertain of whether you skipped it when you copied it, If it's not in the code, then it may be that. 
I retrieved the information [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/)

Comment: I skipped it when I was copying it for security reasons.